# How to insert data from modal and close it

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I'm writing a lightning component that does the below.

1. Clicking a button will pop a new form(Modal).
2. I will fill the form and hit the save button in that Modal.
3. The data gets inserted into the backend, and once Inserted the Modal closes automatically and refreshes the table.

Below is my code.

```
<aura:component controller="TestAssistClass" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="TestAssistContact__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="newItem" type="TestAssistContact__c" 

default="{                                                          
'sobjectType':'TestAssistContact__c',                                      
'Name':'',
'UserType__c':'Employee',                                                                            
'UpdateComments__c':'',                                                                            
'Email__c':''}" />

    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="New Contact" title="New Contact" onclick="{!c.openModal}" />
        <lightning:datatable
                             aura:id="dataTableX"
                             keyField="Id"
                             data="{!v.data}"
                             columns="{!v.columns}"
                             onsave="{!c.handleSaveEdition}"
                             onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"/>
    </div>

    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" aura:id="Modalbox" class="slds-modal slds-modal_large">

        <div class="slds-modal__container" style="width: 65%;">
            <div class="slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-right_xx-large">
                <div class="slds-page-header" style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;, padding-right: 9px;, padding-left: 10px;">
                    <h3 style="font-size: 1rem;" title="">Custom Contact</h3>
                </div> 
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">

                    <div class="slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-right_xx-large">
                        <div class="slds-page-header" style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;, padding-right: 9px;, padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h3 style="font-size: 1rem;" title="">Add your Contact</h3>
                        </div> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-p-top_medium">
                        <div class="slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-horizontal_x-large " >
                            <lightning:input aura:id="newUserForm" label="User Name" name="userName" value="{!v.newItem.Name}"  /> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size_5-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-small slds-p-horizontal_x-large " >
                            <lightning:input aura:id="newUserForm" label="Email" name="userEmail" value="{!v.newItem.Email__c}"/> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-p-top_x-small">
                        <div class="slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-large slds-p-horizontal_x-large " >
                            <lightning:input aura:id="newUserForm" label="User Type" name="userType" value="{!v.newItem.UserType__c}"/> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size_5-of-12 slds-p-left_xx-small slds-p-horizontal_x-large " >
                            <lightning:input aura:id="newUserForm" label="Comments" name="userComments" value="{!v.newItem.UpdateComments__c}" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <lightning:button type="branded" label="Save Contact" onclick="{!c.saveItm}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <ui:button label="close" press="{!c.closeModal}"  />
                </div>
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop " aura:id="Modalbackdrop"></div>   

</aura:component>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
  saveItm : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log(component.get("v.recordId")+'------');
    var newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newItem));
    helper.saveItms(component, newItem);

    var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
    var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpBack,'slds-backdrop--open');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    navEvt.fire(); 
},
  closeModal:function(component,event,helper){    
        var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
        var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpBack,'slds-backdrop--open');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open'); 
    },
    openModal:function(component,event,helper) {
        var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
        var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
        $A.util.addClass(cmpBack, 'slds-backdrop--open'); 
    }
})
```

**helper.js**

```
({
 saveItms : function(component, newItem){
        var recordsEdited = newItem.length;
        var action= component.get('c.saveItem');
        action.setParams({
            "item":newItem
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('State is : ' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            if(response.getReturnValue() === true){
                this.showToast({
                    "title": "Record Added",
                    "type": "success",
                    "message": recordsEdited+" Account Records Added"
                });
                this.reloadDataTable();
            } else{ //if update got failed
                this.showToast({
                    "title": "Error!!",
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Error in update"
                });
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },


    /*
     * Show toast with provided params
     * */
    showToast : function(params){
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if(toastEvent){
            toastEvent.setParams(params);
            toastEvent.fire();
        } else{
            console.log(params);
            alert(params.message);
        }
    },

    /*
     * reload data table
     * */
    reloadDataTable : function(){
        var refreshEvent = $A.get("e.force:refreshView");
        if(refreshEvent){
            refreshEvent.fire();
        }
    }
})
```

**ApexController**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static boolean saveItem(TestAssistContact__c item){
        try{
            upsert item;
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Currently my code is working perfectly, but after I enter the data in the poped up form and hit submit, I need to close the pop manually and do a refresh in the main page to see the changes, but I want this to be done automatically.

Please let me know on how can I do this by modifying the code.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is once record gets created, You should close the modal as you are using for:-

```
<ui:button label="close" press="{!c.closeModal}"  />
```

You need to change saveItm method as:-

```
saveItm : function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('Eneterd Here');
        var newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newItem));
        helper.saveItms(component, newItem);
        var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
        var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpBack,'slds-backdrop--open');
        $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
           navEvt.setParams({
           "recordId": recordid of main page where you are refreshing
           });
           navEvt.fire(); 
    },
```

What i am doing here is:-

After calling saveItms helper method, we are closing the popup and navigating to record so that you get a refreshed view.

Comment: Hi Sanket, Thanks for the quick response... how can I get `recordid of main page where you are refreshing`

Comment: Where you have placed your component? Let say, you have placed your component in Account record detail page, then use component.get("v.recordId") to get the current record id. Make sure you have implemented force:hasrecordId in your component markup.

Comment: It is a custom object

Comment: It will work. Use this:  "recordId":  component.get("v.recordId")   and change your component markup to <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

Comment: when I try this previous comment approach, I'm getting the following error. `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:titleHeader$controller$saveItm [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:titleHeader$controller$saveItm}` :(

Comment: Can you make changes in your question what you tried now by updating the current code?

Comment: updated my question when I do a `    console.log(component.get("v.recordId")+'------');
`, it is giving me undefined :(

Comment: youve implemented your component on multiple interfaces, where exactly are you using the component? is it a record page? if not, recordId be undefined regardless, additionally, if you dont add the recordId attribute, it will also be undefined